# How to connect from home PC to Virtualbox/KVM that hosted on Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu server, it's 3TB HDD space total and 24GB RAM, I want to take 1 little bit of space and RAM to make VPS Windows using VirtualBox or KVM.

**I want to install Windows Server 2008 on VirtualBox OR KVM, and I want to remote desktop from my home PC directly to the VPS I create with Vitualbox, and with network on.**

But after searching internet for 2 days, I couldn't make it work, especially for the network part.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file :

```
Hetzner Online AG - installimage
 Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
  device: eth0
 auto  eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address   46.4.21.70
     broadcast 46.4.21.127
    netmask   255.255.255.192
    gateway   46.4.21.65
     # default route to access subnet
     up route add -net 46.4.21.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 46.4.21.65 eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
     address 2a01:4f8:131:410c::2
     netmask 64
      gateway fe80::1
```

The `ifconfig` command:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:7a:e8:62
          inet addr:46.4.21.70  Bcast:46.4.21.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fe7a:e862/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:131:410c::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:302059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:102335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:392562631 (392.5 MB)  TX bytes:10964261 (10.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:42736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3754256 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:3754256 (3.7 MB)
```

The IP 46.4.21.70 is my Ubuntu server IP.

I tried set up network for the Virtualbox using NAT : could connect to the internet if using Virtualbox start from it, but I heard people say NAT can't be seen by outside world.

I tried selected Bridged Adapter:

[image]

No internet access and here is the ipconfig I did on Windows server in Virtualbox:

[image]

I'm very noob on this network thing, could anyone show me step by step how to do it, would be appreciate :D.

Comment: Give a static address for your windows machine that's in the same range of your Ubuntu IP.

Comment: @KasiyA Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to show you. But easily go to netwoking in Windows and give an IP To your machine. FROM WINDOWS

Comment: @NewUSer with NAT or Bridged Adapter selected? I dont even know which static address have the same range with my Ubuntu server.

Comment: In case of bridged go and give an IP for your windows machine..... Normally as if you are using a desktop with Windows inside.  just give it an IP that make you get Internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ifconfig of the ubuntu machine the ip range is:
46.4.21.65 - 46.4.21.126
(use http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ if you cant work it out)

The ip you specified on the windows server is in the 192.168 range, which is not on the same subnet.

You need to specify the IP in the windows server (to one that is free) something like:

- IP address: 46.4.21.80
- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.192
- Default gateway: 46.4.21.65

DNS server : 208.67.222.222 or a valid internal one if you have one (I assume you might be making the windows server a dns server so you could set it to itself AFTER installing the dns role ie: 127.0.0.1)

This will allow connectivity. One question, why do you have such a strange IP range on the ubuntu server (46.4....) is it a public IP or something? Normally you seperate your servers with a firewall rather than assigning a public IP to the interface, for security concerns.

Pete

Comment: @allenbone
Hi there. I tried to make it work by using NAT, and port forwarding the port, and it's working.
Thanks for your method, I will try it later though and will let you know if this work too.
For the IP, it is the IP that Hetzner (my server provider) gave me, I dont want to mess up with the network so I leave it default.

Comment: What I have suggested, will work fine. Just check there is nothing using the same IP I suggested, or use any free one in that range.

Are you on a cable network or something - it could be an internal range but 46.4... looks like a public address to me? Normally you have a router separating your internal computers from the outside world. Did they not send you a router? 

The only reason I ask is that it sounds like the method you are currently using is assigning public IP's to the pc's you have on the network. How do you connect things like your iphone or whatever?

Comment: No, they dont send a router and I dont seperate any internal comp, They just gave me the IP and ssh detail, that was it. I'm not sure about public IP neither 

I'm using "attached to NAT" and port forwarding to the port I want to use, then on remote desktop I put the server IP (which is 46.4....) : port number.

Still not try the method you suggested, but sure will try it tonight. but hopefully it will work. even it could work but I dont think I know the difference between the 2 methods.

Comment: The bridged connector is preferable in my opinion, as it introduces less overhead and processing on the packets moving to and from the NIC. Some functions will not work behind the NAT option, such as if you wanted to configure your windows server to run Routing and Remote access.
The bridged adaptor allows these functions to run because there is no NAT in between the Virtual machine and the external world.

Comment: I just test it.. It...doesn't work. I put the settings just like you mentioned, The DNS is : 208.68.220.220   208.67.222.222, but no Internet Connection. and can not connect from my home PC.

Comment: Here is the picture of setting : http://i.imgur.com/IGFwNub.jpg

Comment: How confident are you the subnet mask you are using is correct? Is this what the provider gave you?

Are you able to ping 46.4.21.65?

If not, when you alter the IP address to 46.4.21.69 on the windows server are you able to ping 46.4.21.65?

This is apparently the gateway out so this should reply. Can you ping that address from the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I just noticed you wrote this: "and can not connect from my home PC".
Obviously you need to have local internet access working before it can work in virtualbox etc. Is this not working or something?

Comment: I dont really know. The only thing they gave me is the ssh login detail. 
I just check. Here is what I see in the login page of my server : http://i.imgur.com/OSyHFlS.jpg
is this the subnet you're talking about?
No, I can not ping the 46.4.21.65 from my home PC, no request received.

Comment: It looks like an IPv6 address. Does the home PC get internet by using IPV6 and not IPV4? What setting information did you actually get from the ISP to type into your compter? Also I just want to verify that you have local internet access, before troubleshooting anything with the VM.

Comment: My home connection is fine, it using IPV4, I can't disable IPv6 and still getting the internet. 
Oh, look like 46.4.21.80 is another server, not from mine. that's why I can ping it, but not my server. yeah set to ...21.69 and 81, still not internet access and can not ping it.
The only way I can make it work is using NAT. Not sure this method not working.

Comment: Did your ISP only provide you with 1 IP address usable - ie the one that you already specified for the Ubuntu server? If you are only allowed 1 IP and you applied it to the server, then there are none left over to use for the windows machine. This is why normally the IP is put onto a router - to allow many devices to connect behind that router (thats its job - route packets from the network behind it on its behalf).

Comment: @Pete : No, my PC ISP has nothing to do with the Ubuntu server, the Ubuntu server is from Hetzner, server provider, like any other servers, they must have their own network (for webhosting, streaming, gaming, stuff, ..) The Hetzner network is still at default state, I didn't touch anything to it yet. The IP 46.4.... is from hetzner too, not my PC ISP.

Comment: Here is what I found out another way to to this : 
Allocate two Network Interfaces to Windows VM

Adapter 1 - "Host Only Adapter" (IP assigns automatically via DHCP)

Adapter 2  - "NAT" (IP assigns automatically via DHCP)

THis method works for me, using only IP address when put in rdp, but...it doesnt ask for password, that's the downside.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, you have bought a remote server somewhere on the internet running Ubuntu and want to install windows server inside that remote server on VirtualBox. 
If this is the case, then you cannot use your windows server for RRAS or anything like that. The correct method is actually the one you already used - using it in NAT mode in the VM config and doing the port forward to 3389. That will give you the username/password prompt.

If you intend to use your Windows server as a RRAS server,  you will need to buy another server from this company running windows.

Comment: To clarify -  you cannot use a bridged adaptor in this environment, unless you reconfigure the entire Ubuntu Server to act only as a router/firewall (do nothing else). I would guess that is not desired, since you can bypass that simply buy using windows on the remote server you bought, rather than linux.

Comment: I thought you knew it at the first time :D? Oh but that's ok. I guess I can only use NAT, which working for me. Yeah I wanted to find a way to remote it because I dont want to spend extra bucks on another windows server. Thanks for your help then. Although the solution did not work for me but I still give it +1 and accepted answer :D.